# Is there a way to write this query positively? Or at least more clearly?

Tags: sql

I want to select DESCRIPTIONs where all associated ITEMs are in another table.

One table associates DESCRIPTIONs to ITEMs:

```
DESCRIPTION   ITEM
mouse         item1
mouse         item2
keyboard      item3
```

Another lists ITEMs. (There's data about them I'm eliding here)

```
ITEMS   ...   ...
item1
item2
item3
```

My query is slow and incorporates a double negative.

```
select distinct A.DESCRIPTION
from   DESCRIPTION_TO_ITEM_TABLE A
where  A.DESCRIPTION not in (select distinct B.DESCRIPTION
                           from DESCRIPTION_TO_ITEM_TABLE B
                            where B.ITEM not in (select distinct C.ITEM from ITEM_TABLE C))
```

Basically, it's saying
select descriptions where the descriptions are not among those descriptions with items not in the item table

In other words, select the descriptions that *do* have all their items in the item table.

Is there a way to write that query explicitly?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Syntax varies between them, and the solution might be different based on which database you're using. When posting SQL questions, it's typically a good idea to add a DBMS specific tag (like MySQL or SQL Server) as well as the generic SQL tag.

Comment: I belive the inner join is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you want all records where the an item intersect a description

```
Select description
from descriptions d
inner join items  i
on i.items = d.item
```

if this is what you're after... I strongly encourage
 the following reading: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

But perhaps you'r saying that if the description mouse... has 2 items and one of them doesn't appear in the item table you don't want to see it...

subquery to get descriptions that don't have all items.
then select to get descriptions not in that list.

```
Select description from description where description not in (
Select description 
from descriptions d
left join items i
on i.items = d.item
where i.item is null)
```

or

Subquery to get those descriptions missing an item
then join back to subquery and return only those records that are not in that list.

```
Select c.description 
from description c
LEFT JOIN (Select description 
from descriptions d
left join items i
on i.items = d.item
where i.item is null) B on B.Description = c.description
and B.Description is null
```

Comment: -1 because this doesn't give the same results. If you've got description `A` with items `1`, `2`, `3`, and only `1` and `2` are found in the other table, your query will incorrectly return `A`.

Comment: I accept the -1 which is why I prefaced my response with if I understand the question correctly.  It's also why I revisited it using two alternative methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can left join to your `ITEM_TABLE`, and then compare the number of attempted matches to the number of actual matches:

```
select DESCRIPTION_TO_ITEM_TABLE.DESCRIPTION
from DESCRIPTION_TO_ITEM_TABLE
left join ITEM_TABLE
on ITEM_TABLE.ITEM = DESCRIPTION_TO_ITEM_TABLE.ITEM
group by DESCRIPTION_TO_ITEM_TABLE.DESCRIPTION
having count(ITEM_TABLE.ITEM) = count(DESCRIPTION_TO_ITEM_TABLE.ITEM)
```

Comment: The assumption being that description and item in description are unique as well as item in items.  otherwise the counts don't work.

Comment: @xQbert It will still work if duplicate items exist.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be more efficient to add a field in the items or descriptions table which tells you whether you have all items.